# how to create room in QuickBlox using WEB SDK

Tags: quickblox

I want to implement group chat using QuickBlox(web). Normally for a group chat we will login to QuickBlox, go to chat and will create a group.Instead of this is there any possibilities
to create rooms programmatically by user? if possible please help me how can I achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now WebSDK doesn't support a wrraper around XMPP API, so you should include additional XMPP JS library for that.

Strophe.js (http://strophe.im/strophejs/)

and its Strophe.muc plugin (https://github.com/QuickBlox/sample-chat-xmpp-web/blob/master/js/libs/strophe.muc.js).

Please use these methods for creating the chat room:

1) `muc.createInstantRoom`

2) `muc.configure`

3) `muc.saveConfiguration`

Comment: Can you please provide samples(links/references) so that I can refer and implement according to my requirements.I am not understanding what parameters I have to pass and get the result.Please help me...Thanks in advance

Comment: Strophe is a third-party product which we don't support. Maybe you can find some information in web about Strophe muc plugin and its code samples or seek support from the creator.

Comment: Or you can use the other xmpp js library, not only Strophe. Strophe.js is more low-level library which we recommended to use together with our WebSDK because they can be united quite easy. That we're showing in our samples (example, https://github.com/QuickBlox/sample-chat-xmpp-web/tree/master) but we haven't used the programmatical creating the chat rooms yet.

Comment: Currently QuickBlox has an own web XMPP Chat plugin for WebSDK. You can look the all documentation here: http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Comment: @WebDev why is the particular section of creating a room under "Chat plugin API (Deprecated)"? does it mean we should no longer use it? is there some other way for a user to programmatically create a room?